# Proving language is not context free using pumping lemma

Tags: computer-science, computability, pumping-lemma

Hi I'm completely stuck on an exercise which is to prove this language is not context free using pumping lemma for context free languages:

```
L = {xyz | x + y = z} , where the alphabet is from 0-9, so for example
10^m20^m30^m ∈ L for all m ≥ 0 (since 1+2 =3, 10 + 20 = 30, etc)
```

How would you solve this using the pumping lemma for context free languages? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Try to imitate the proof given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) that $a^nb^nc^n$ is not context-free.

Comment: I have tried to replicate already and was looking at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdfE0IcGaJs&t=57s
, but I can't figure out how it connects to amount of 0s etc and I imagine it's not exactly the same. But thank you anyway. @saulspatz

Comment: Simple question. When dividing string = uvxyz, can |u|=0? I'm wondering because if that the case then vxy could contain 10i where i>=p, but I'm not sure. Thank you! @saulspatz

Comment: According to Wikipedia, yes $|u|=0$ is allowed.  I can't pretend that I remember all the technicalities of the definition myself.